# Incorrect output shown when implementing program in C++

Tags: c++

In this code I am basically building a program for a health club.
The user inputs the desired membership and months and then it prints the total fees.
The program runs perfectly for option 2&4 however for 1 it gives two outputs and for 3 none at all.
I guess there is a slight bug in my code which I really cant find.
The program is fine for 2 but tit calculates two values for 1 and it displays none for 3.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void menu ()
{
    cout << "\n\t\tHealth Club Membership Menu\n\n";
    cout << "1. Standard Adult Membership\n";
    cout << "2. Child Membership\n";
    cout << "3. Senior Citizen Membership\n";
    cout << "4. Quit the Program\n\n";
    cout << "Enter your choice: ";

}
void fees(int member,int months)
{
    cout<<"The fees is Rs.";
    cout<<(member*months);
}

int main()
{

    int  months, choice;
    int adult=40;
    int child=20;
    int senior=50;
     do{menu();

    {

        cin>>choice;
        if (choice>=4)
        {
            cout<<"You have quit your membership\n";
            return 0;
        }
        cout<<"Please enter the number of months you want"<<endl;
        cin>>months;


        switch (choice)
        {
            case 0:
            choice==1;
            fees(adult,months);
        }
            case 1:
                {
                    choice==2;
                    fees(child,months);
                    }
        case 2:
            {
                choice==3;
                    fees(senior,months);

            }



    }
    }




}
    while((choice>=1) || (choice<4));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: 1) Fix your indenting and general code formatting. 2) Review the [break statement](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/break).

Comment: `choice==1;` does nothing.

Answer (score 1):

I have corrected some parts of your program. Here is mine.

**My Program**

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void fees(int member, int months); //function prototype to calculate fees for members of differing age groups
void menu(); //function prototype to display options

void menu()
{
    cout << "\n\t\tHealth Club Membership Menu\n\n";
    cout << "1. Standard Adult Membership\n";
    cout << "2. Child Membership\n";
    cout << "3. Senior Citizen Membership\n";
    cout << "4. Quit the Program\n\n";
    cout << "Enter your choice: ";

}

void fees(int member,int months)
{
    cout<<"The fees is Rs.";
    cout<<(member*months);
}

int main()
{
    
    int months, choice;
    int senior=50;
    int adult=40;
    int child=20;
    
    menu(); //invoke menu method
    
    cin>>choice;
    if (choice == 4)
        {
            cout<<"You have quit your membership\n";
            return 0;
        }
        
        cout<<"Please enter the number of months you want"<<endl;
        cin>>months;


        switch (choice)
        {
            case 1:
            fees(adult,months);
            break;
        
            case 2:
            fees(child,months);
            break;
                    
            case 3:
            fees(senior,months);
            break;
            
            default:
            return 0; //exit program if choice is out of range
        }    
    return 0;
}
```

**Output for choice 1**

```
Enter your choice: 1
Please enter the number of months you want
3
The fees is Rs.120
```

**Output for choice 3**

```
Enter your choice: 3
Please enter the number of months you want
5
The fees is Rs.250
```

**Output for choice 2**

```
Enter your choice: 2
Please enter the number of months you want
6
The fees is Rs.120
```

As you can see I have tried indenting the code to make sure is neat. Like what **v.p.** said in the previous comment, since you have declared choice in the **`switch statement`**, there is no need to include `choice==1 or etc`. You will only put that in the `if-else parentheses` when you want to implement conditions. Eventually, all your choices will work. Most importantly, please read up C++ documentations properly and don't do for the sake of doing it or else you will struggle. Hope this answers your question:)

Comment: Two things. 
1) I wanted the program in a loop so that after completion once it automatically displays the menu and the program runs again.
2) Can you please guide me towards the authentic resources.

Comment: @Kh.Murad it doesn't make sense to run the whole thing again even if the choice is correct. Like it's not gonna make any sense from a logical perspective. You only need to loop when there is at least 1 set of instructions to execute in this instance here

Comment: And also the fact that this is a simple program, this can be done while loop for loop etc even try-catch exception will work too.

Answer (score 0):

You need break statements.  That's probably why you get two outputs for a choice of 1.

You have no case statement for a choice of 3.  That's why you get no output for 3.

Why are you implementing a switch case for 0? Seems unnecessary.

By the way, All of your lines like `choice==1` don't actually do anything in your code, nor do you need it.  Get rid of them.

Lastly, fix your indentation.